# Laravel: $request->all() gives empty array when called with json xhr

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

For some reason I cannot use $.ajax, only the XMLHttpRequest.
I need to send json to laravel controller. When I tried it, I only got 500s

Here's how I make the request:

```
    const sendEdit = function(){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/blog/edit");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
        let data = {};
        data.header = $("#editHeader").val();
        data.body = $("#editBody").val();
        data.postId = {{$post->id}};
        data.userId = {{Auth::user()->id}}
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(d){
        }
        xhr.send([data]);
    }
```

The controller returned 500. When I tried to var_dump $request->json() or $request->all() it showed me an error. Here's my controller. Please help me access the data in JSON

```
 public function edit(Request $request){
         echo(var_dump($request->all()));
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect us to __guess__ the error?

Comment: erm, what? I don't mean guessing the error, but how to access data passed by json. Also, yeah, I do, I used it only to find out why is the controller giving 500

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you for being super toxic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not using JSON.stringify() before sending the request.